# Which method is called when the screen is displayed from the Navigation Stack in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React Native and I am using

```
import {  createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
```

for navigation from one screen to next and displaying a screen from the stack on the back button press.

I want to focus TextInput when the screen is displayed from the stack.

```
FirstScreen -> SecondScreen (Back Button Press)-> FirstScreen (Focus TextInput)
```

Which method is called in the FirstScreen when it is displayed from the stack?

I tried putting code in `ComponentDidMonunt(), ComponentWillMount(), render(), ComponentWillUnmount()` methods but these methods are not called when FirstScreen is displayed from the stack.

Comment: use navigation.addListener('focus', () => { focus text input here }) in first page

Comment: I put  componentDidMount() { const { navigation } = this.props; navigation.addListener('focus', () => { console.log("Focus Method Called")}) }  in the FirstScreen but this method was not called when I pressed back button on SecondScreen  and FirstScreen was displayed from navigation stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try **NavigationEvent** in react-navigation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/

```js
class Profile extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this._unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // do something
      this.emailInput.focus()
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._unsubscribe();
  }

  render() {
      <View>
        <TextInput ref={ref => { this.emailInput = ref; }}/>
      <View/>
  }
}
```